# Need help to debug this updateLink resolver

Tags: graphql-js

I need to implement an updateLink to my graphQL server, but it keeps throwing 'id is not defined' error. The server doesn't have a database yet, only an array for practice purpose.

I have defined the schema for the mutation for update, also wrote the resolver, but it just didn't work.I have looked into the apollo document, it seems my resolver and schema are correct.

The following is the resolver

```
 updateLink:(parent,args)=>{
            const link = {  
                id:args.id,              
                description:args.description,
                url:args.url,
            }
            links[Number(id)]=link
            return link
        }
    },
```

The following the schema

```
type Query {
  info: String!
  feed: [Link!]!
  link(id:ID!):Link
}

type Mutation {
  post(url: String!, description: String!): Link!
  updateLink(id:ID!,url:String!, description: String!): Link
  delete(id:ID!):Link
}

type Link {
  id: ID!
  description: String!
  url: String!
}
```

The expected outcome should be the update of the server of the link array, but I got the following error instead.

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateLink": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "id is not defined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "updateLink"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You reference a variable called `id` here:

```
links[Number(id)]=link
```

but you have not defined a variable with that name as the error indicates. I would suggest adding a linter to your project to help you catch errors like that.